# net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to establish connection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, websocket

I've been following some tutorials on making a chat system using asp.net and a bit of javascript but I've run into a problem. The project works fine up until it trys to create the websocket. Instead of creating it and moving on it just gives me the error:

> failed: Error in connection establishment: net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I've been trying to sort out the problem for about 3 hours now but I've had no luck. I've tryed using xampp and running apache but it hasn't worked. Here's my code:
Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

        var name = prompt('what is your name?:');

        var url = 'ws://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname.replace('index.html', 'ws.ashx') + '?name=' + name;

        alert('Connecting to: ' + url);

        ws = new WebSocket(url);

        ws.onopen = function () {

        $('#messages').prepend('Connected <br/>');

        $('#cmdSend').click(function () {

        ws.send($('#txtMessage').val());

        $('#txtMessage').val('');

        });

        };

        ws.onmessage = function (e) {

        $('#chatMessages').prepend(e.data + '<br/>');

        };

        $('#cmdLeave').click(function () {

        ws.close();

        });

        ws.onclose = function () {

        $('#chatMessages').prepend('Closed <br/>');

        };

        ws.onerror = function (e) {

        $('#chatMessages').prepend('Oops something went wront <br/>');

        };

        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <input id="txtMessage" />

    <input id="cmdSend" type="button" value="Send" />

    <input id="cmdLeave" type="button" value="Leave" />

    <br />

    <div id="chatMessages" />

</body>

</html>
```

ws.ashx:

public class WSHttpHandler : IHttpHandler

```
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

        {

            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)

            context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(new TestWebSocketHandler());

        }

        public bool IsReusable

        {

            get

            {

            return false;

            }

        }

    }
```

and TestWebSocketHandler.cs:

```
    public class TestWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler

    {

        private static WebSocketCollection clients = new WebSocketCollection();

        private string name;

        public override void OnOpen()

        {

            this.name = this.WebSocketContext.QueryString["name"];

            clients.Add(this);

            clients.Broadcast(name + " has connected.");

        }

        public override void OnMessage(string message)

        {

            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} said: {1}", name, message));

        }

        public override void OnClose()

        {

            clients.Remove(this);

            clients.Broadcast(string.Format("{0} has gone away.", name));

        }

    }
```

Comment: paste in code connected with ws not link to all project's files.

Comment: Can someone please help?